# Stateless widget to Stateful widget convert Dart Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

This is my code :

```html
class StocksDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final String degisimoran;
  final String? sondeger;
  final String? hacim;
  final String? mindeger;
  final String maxdeger;
  final String? zaman;
  final String? hisseismi;
  final String? hissekodu;



  const StocksDetailScreen({
Key? key,
required this.degisimoran,
required this.sondeger,
required this.hacim,
required this.mindeger,
required this.maxdeger,
required this.zaman,
required this.hisseismi,
required this.hissekodu,


  }) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

I need to convert it to stateful widget because I will use setstate. but when I implement my const (which I call from API) in stateful I get null safety errors. what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your cursor at statelessWidget word and press Alt + Enter (android studio) and you will get an option to convert statefulWidgets. You can convert easily.

Answer (score 2):

Press `ctrl+.` on vs-code to get convert option, and select option

[image]

While the data is nullable, you can remove required, if not needed.

```dart
class StocksDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String degisimoran;
  final String? sondeger;
  final String? hacim;
  final String? mindeger;
  final String maxdeger;
  final String? zaman;
  final String? hisseismi;
  final String? hissekodu;
  const StocksDetailScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.degisimoran,
    this.sondeger,
    this.hacim,
    this.mindeger,
    required this.maxdeger,
    this.zaman,
    this.hisseismi,
    this.hissekodu,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StocksDetailScreen> createState() => _StocksDetailScreenState();
}

class _StocksDetailScreenState extends State<StocksDetailScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```